# Weird array/pointer behavior when derefencing char*

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have this 64 byte character array `buf`.

I am trying to dereference the value at byte[4] as an little-endian integer. But what I get out is not equivalent to the bytes when I look character by character.

See below for the behavior that is confusing me:

```
(gdb) p &buf + 4
$106 = (char (*)[64]) 0xbffff8c8

// These are the four bytes (little-endian)
(gdb) p/x buf[4]
$111 = 0x9a
(gdb) p/x buf[5]
$112 = 0xff
(gdb) p/x buf[6]
$113 = 0xff
(gdb) p/x buf[7]
$114 = 0xbf

//and here's buf[3] just for reference
(gdb) p/x buf[3]
$119 = 0xb


// Then why does dereferencing 0xbffff8c8 not yield 0xbfffff9a ??
(gdb) p/x *(0xbffff8c8)
$117 = 0xbffff8e4
```

Comment: packing/alignment/other compiler crap? Why would you do that?

Comment: Cast everything to plain `char*` and then redo the experiment. Do you get the same results? (I suspect that `buf[4]` and `buf[5]` etc are 64 bytes apart.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that pointer  arithmetic takes the size of the data type into account. Since the size of `buf` is 64 bytes, `&buf + 4` is a pointer to memory 4*64=256 bytes after `&buf`.

To get a pointer to `buf[4]` use `&buf[4]`.

Answer (score 1):

From your example it would appear that `buf[4]` and `buf[5]` etc are 64 bytes apart.

On the other hand, the last command (`$117`) reads contiguous bytes.

Try casting everything to plain char* and redoing the experiment.